# Show Image/animation from boot to loaded chromium site

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I asked something like that on Stack Overflow, and somebody said I should ask that here. So, here I am :D

I have an HTML site that shows some data from the sensors (read with Python), and I want to make it look professional. Seeing the boot, desktop, starting of Chrome, etc. looks so "non professional", especially for "Jugend Forscht". So if I could add an animation (image should also be enough) from boot to the complete site, it would look better.

Would be nice if you could help me/us :)

Infos:

Raspberry Pi 3
  - Display over HDMI
  - Raspbian with Chromium

I've heard, that it's also possible to disable x so it doesn't show anything until it has loaded. Would be possible, but doesn't look so good.

Thanks for reading,

Fabian

PS: I have often seen, that chromium shows some errors like "Chromium was not closed correctly" or something like that. It would be cool if I could prevent this. Can "Electron" prevent this? If yes, can Electron read GPIOs with Python?